# Tasks runs only after admin is logged in

Tags: plugin-development, tasks, craft2

I have a plugin which runs a task on order complete. The tasks runs successfully without any errors. But the problem is the task is only completed when admin is logged in. So if someone has completed the order, they have to wait until an admin logs in to dashboard. What could I be missing? The code I'm using is :

`CustomPlugin.php`

```
craft()->on('commerce_orders.onOrderComplete', [$this, 'initializeTask']);

public function initializeTask(Event $event){
    $order = $event->params['order'];
    foreach ($order->lineItems as $lineItem) {
        craft()->tasks->createTask('Custom', null, [
            'id' => $order->id,
        ]);
    }
}
```

`CustomTask.php`

```
class CustomTask extends BaseTask
{
    protected function defineSettings()
    {
        return [
            'id' => AttributeType::Number,
        ];
    }

    public function getDescription()
    {
        return 'Custom Task';
    }

    public function getTotalSteps()
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public function runStep($step)
    {
        $orderId = $this->getSettings()->orderId;
        .
        .
        .
        return true;
    }
}
```

Is there any type of priority or setting that needs to be set?

Answer (score 1):

Got it. Added the following code.

```
if (!craft()->tasks->isTaskRunning()){
    $task = craft()->tasks->getNextPendingTask();

    if ($task){
        craft()->tasks->runPendingTasks();
    }
}
```